# Ansible variable in var file

Tags: ansible

How can I call defined Ansible variable from same file?
Here is my code:

```
php:
  php_location: etc/php/7.0
  php_mods_available_location: /{{php_location}}/mods-available
  php_fpm_conf_location: /{{php_location}}/fpm/conf.d
  php_cli_conf_location: /{{php_location}}/cli/conf.d
```

"php_location" is undefined.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a variable named `php_location`.  You have a variable named `php`, the value of which will be a dictionary with a key named `php_location`.

To do what you want, you would need to do something like:

```
php_location: etc/php/7.0
php:
  php_location: "{{ php_location }}"
  php_mods_available_location: "/{{php_location}}/mods-available"
  php_fpm_conf_location: "/{{php_location}}/fpm/conf.d"
  php_cli_conf_location: "/{{php_location}}/cli/conf.d"
```